# How do I get a equals sign under letters?

Tags: math-mode, stacking-symbols

To show that a letter is a matrix my math book puts a equals sign under the letter. 
How do I do this?

Comment: It's a very old fashioned notation, from the typewriter times.

Answer (score 12):

That notation is quite old fashioned. If you really want to use it, probably the best way is to define

```
\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\underline{\underline{#1}}
```

Here, for comparison, the result of `\matr{A}` and of `\underset{=}{A}`:

[image: rendered output]

In any case, define your own command, so that you can easily change your mind later; with `\underset` it would be

```
\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\underset{=}{#1}}
```

According to ISO norms, variables denoting matrices should be in boldface italic:

```
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\bm{#1}}
```

(or, simply, `\newcommand{\matr}{\bm}` or, even more simply, `\let\matr\bm`).

Comment: I think `\uuline` from `ulem` package will give nicer results then a double `underline`

Comment: The lines are nearer to each other with `uuline`; the result is ugly nonetheless. :) ISO norms say that variables denoting matrices should be in boldface italics.

Comment: I never said I like this typesetting ;) I also prefer bold matrix variables.

Comment: I'd plus one this again for the advice "define your own command (anyway)", if I could. This is somewhere high up on the list of good ideas, and saves significant time when the journal I'm sending a paper to changes.

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
equal sign under letter: $\underset{=}{a}$
\[ \underset{=}{a} \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `amsmath` package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
   \[\underset{=}{A}=
     \begin{pmatrix}
        1&2\\3&4
     \end{pmatrix}
   \]
\end{document}
```

result will be:

[image: result]

or use `ulem` package for double underlining. I think this will result in a nicer spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\[\uuline{A}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2\\3&4
\end{pmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

(amsmath is only used for pmatrix environment)
result is:

[image: result]